# How do I cleanly install speaker wire in a mobile home?

Tags: wiring, crawlspace

I have a decent amount of experience with all sorts of wiring in houses and offices. However all of my experience relates to buildings which have attics or dropped ceilings.

I now am installing speakers on the deck of a double wide mobile home. I want to conceal the speaker wire the best I can. In a typical house I would run the wire to the attic and drop it though the soffit right at the speaker. However, with no attic in the mobile home I am not confident on the best approach. Is it possible to run the speaker wire through the exterior wall from under the house to the top part of the wall where the speaker will be hung? Are there any other approaches I should consider?

Comment: Whatever scheme you use, keep in mind that there are a lot of sharp edges.  You need to use a wiring technique that will protect the wire from being cut by these edges.

Comment: Safest bet would be to surface mount and forget concealment. Mobile home walls are miserable {expletives, many expletives, deleted} to work in.

Answer (score 1):

Using the walls and floor is really the only way.

If you go through the floor or walls you have to use listed speaker wire.

not the clear stuff we used to get through hobby stores or Amazon.

The listed stuff costs 5-6x what the clear stuff will do in some cases using plastic low voltage Chanel inside can be much less expensive.

With listed speaker wire you can go in a wall and down through the floor. There are a lot fewer restrictions on low voltage using parts like the “not a box” low voltage mount frames. that is used to mount low voltage connection points. You still need to support the wires under the structure but most mobile’s or Modular’s have a fair amount of space to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run through floor
However some things to consider are, what is in that particular wall ? 1-wiring 2- plumbing,including vent pipes.
It is by far the most difficult of jobs for concealing wires.
I have had good luck with the trim and corner molding wire concealing systems.
You can also try wireless speakers but then you usually have a power issue.
Good luck.
This may be one of those times its best to just pay the piper AND the PRO and have it done right the first time

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).